# smarty email template modify in VTiger

Tags: php, smarty, vtiger

I am quite new in VTiger CRM but I do have a good knowledge at PHP/mySQL, CSS . I add a select box in `.\Smarty\templates\ComposeEmail.tpl` like:

```
<table>   
<tr>
        <td class="mailSubHeader">Status:</td>
        <td class="mailSubHeader">
            <select name="somename">
                <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="mailSubHeader">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

how can i store the information(in database table) of the selected item when someone submit it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that's an interesting question.. As far as I know, you can pass variables to the *.tpl* from *PHP*, but I'm not sure if you can do it the other way around.

The `ComposeEmail.tpl` is called by *modules/Email/EditView.php*. I know to pass variables to the template, you would use:

```
$smarty->assign("[SMARTY_VARIABLE]",[$php_variable]);
```

Not sure if it works the other way around though.. My guess is you can call a PHP script in the template file, that will do the database storage. The script will need to call the global $adb; variable. Then you can write a SQL statement similar to this:

```
$sql = "select currency_id from vtiger_users where id=?";
$result = $adb->pquery($sql, array($id));
$currencyid=  $adb->query_result($result,0,"currency_id");
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. I will try your solution. I am now working on different project and as I didn't get any answer for my question also didn't find any way to solve that at that particular project(within a very short time) I used the SugarCRM instead of VTiger. Hope someone will try your solution and this help him! Thanks again....;)